# c# mvc DataType.MultilineText with Required and accept enter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have my model with a field for address

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[Display(Name = "Address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

I should have a required textarea and I want to accept return. The render HTML seems correct

```
<textarea name="Address" id="Address" rows="2" cols="20" 
          data-val-required="Address is required." data-val="true" 
          data-val-length-max="1024" 
          data-val-length="Address must be under 1024 chars.">
</textarea>
```

but the field is not required and I can type return.
Any advice? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _I want to accept return_? You want user to be able to click "enter" key to put multiline value?

Comment: Yes exactly. Now If I press enter nothing happend

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Basically a user can insert an address in multiple line. For example: Grand Union House,<br>
20 Kentish Town Road,<br>
London<br>
NW1 9NX

Comment: Yes, but what is your issue? And you have stated _but the field is not required_ - but it is required (it has the `[Required]` attribute) and what do you mean _and I can type return_?

Comment: When I press return the cursor doesn't go in a new line. Unless I add the DataAnnotation [Required], the form isn't blocked if this field is empty

Comment: Still not clear what your asking. You have generated  a `<textarea>` and if you press the 'Enter' key while its focused, then it will add a new line. If that's not happening for you its due to something you have not shown us.

Comment: Also, if you can send this form without any validation errors when you click "Submit" make sure you have indeed included js files responsible for unobtrusive validation.

Comment: @PawełHemperek in my form there are a lot of fields and the validation is working fine apart from this field.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I should have a normal behaviour: if I press "Enter", I want to have a new line but now it doesn't happened.